# How to add confirmation checkbox for FOSUserbundle Registration

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using the FOSUserBundle, how do i add a checkbox that has to be selected for the user to create an account.

Does FOS already cater for this, and perhaps i just have to add a line in the config file, or maybe i have to change the controller some how.

I have added a link to a picture to better explain what i need to do

[image: http://lescouverts.com/Images/errer-fos.png]

This is really important, as users must accept the terms and conditions before registration.

Answer (score 2):

You can add simply à field with the option « mapped » at false for doesn't add it in your entity.

```
$builder
    ->add('cgu', 'checkbox', array(
        'label'     => 'Je reconnais…',
        'required'  => true,
        'mapped' => false
    ))
;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form you will have to use class:

```
         Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\True;
```

like this :

```
        <?php
namespace Project\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\True;

use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType;

class MyUserRegistrationType extends AbstractType
{

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('user', new RegistrationFormType())
        ->add('cgu', 'checkbox', array(
            'label'     => 'Your label',
            'required'  => true
        ))
       ->add('t_and_c', 'checkbox', array(
                'property_path' => false,
                'constraints' => new True(array('message' => 'Your Confirmation Message','groups' => 'Registration')),
        ))
    ;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'project_userbundle_user';
}
}
```

Comment: I had to use `'mapped' => false` instead of `'property_path' => false`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions, the first is the legacy create a legacy from that of FOSUserBundle form. But you can have issues at validating your User entity. 
I suggest you create a form MyUserRegistrationType.php for example and add FOSUserBundle form and checkbox like this :

```
<?php
namespace Project\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType;

class MyUserRegistrationType extends AbstractType
{

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('user', new RegistrationFormType())
        ->add('cgu', 'checkbox', array(
            'label'     => 'Your label',
            'required'  => true
        ))
    ;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'project_userbundle_user';
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajeet's answer is correct for validating the form, but the user can submit the form and then an error will show.  There is another option if you want to prevent the user from being able to submit the form at all and you need to use javascript or jQuery.  I use this and I actually hide the submit button until the user has filled out all items needed.  Below is a simple script using jQuery:

```
<script>
    $('#chkSelect').click(function(){ validatechecked(); });

    validatechecked(){
        var isChecked = $('#chkSelect').prop('checked');
        if(var){
            #submit.show();
        }
        else{
            alert("Please agree to the terms to proceed.")
            #submit.hide();
        }
    };
</script>
```

You will need to adjust the code with the id of your submit button and checkbox.  You can add other options to it for more validation.

I use this along with annotations in my entity to give the user quicker feedback and to prevent clearly wrong/incomplete submissions.  It is something extra you need to add to your twig file and you probably should put the jQuery code in a separate js file.